# Bootstrap input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap tag inputs on email field in my application .Am getting as below (Whenever i hit enter , entered values went out of input field)

[image: Tag Input output]

But i want my input field as like ,(It should accommodate all inputs in text box itself)

[image: Tag Input Expected]

I have added bootstrap and bootstrap taginput js in my code.

Can anyone please help me out to achieve this.

Comment: `bootstrap tags input` already have `close`

Comment: Please provide the relevant codes with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Demo:

```js
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select class="js-example-tags form-control" multiple="multiple" data-width="50%">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```